# Another representation of the law of large numbers

Tags: asymptotics, law-of-large-numbers

Recently I saw the new representation of LLN like below

$n^{-1}\sum X_{i}=E(X) + O_{p}(n^{-1/2}\text{Var}(X)^{-1/2})$

Does anyone verify this?

In the paper, $K()$ is a kernel function

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The expression is a little odd because there's no reason to mention $\text{Var}(X)$ when using "big O" notation.  In any case,

\begin{align}
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i}{n} &= \mu + n^{-1/2} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - \mu)}{\sqrt{n}} \\
&= \mu + O_p(n^{-1/2})
\end{align}

since $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - \mu) / \sqrt{n}$ converges in distribution.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I read this like above edited, which comes from p.15 of http://www.wise.xmu.edu.cn/seta2006/download/ORAL%20PRESENTATION/Ye%20Azhong/Heteroscedasticity-newn.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I could finally find the answer

It is in "Theorem 14.4-1 in Bishop et al"

The question was applied by this theorem for LLN